# JPA @OneToMany with composite primary keys

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, composite-primary-key

I need to map with JPA the following legacy DB table structure I cannot change.
It’s a one to many relationship between table ao_rda_acq (1) ->  ao_rda_acq_righe (many)  (purchase requisition -> purchase requisition rows)

Table (1)

```
create table ao_rda_acq
(
    id_divisione     varchar(4)  not null,
    esercizio        smallint    not null,
    id_rda           varchar(10) not null,
    ...
    other fields
    ...
    constraint pk_ao_rda_acq
        primary key (id_divisione, esercizio, id_rda)   
)
```

table many

```
create table ao_rda_acq_righe
(
    id_divisione     varchar(4) ,
    esercizio        smallint    not null,
    id_rda           varchar(10) not null,
    nr_riga          integer     not null,
    ...
    other fields
    ... 
    constraint pk_ao_rda_righe
        primary key (id_divisione, esercizio, id_rda, nr_riga),
    constraint ao_rda_acq_righe_ao_rda_acq_id_divisione_esercizio_id_rda_fk
        foreign key (id_divisione, esercizio, id_rda) references ao_rda_acq     
)
```

The primary key  of table ao_rda_acq side one of the relationship has 3 fields id_divisione, esercizio, id_rda. The primay key of the table side many of the relationship has the same 3 filed plus a 4th field nr_riga.

I tryed with this JPA approch using @IdClass annotation for composite primary keys

```
@Table(name="ao_rda_acq")
@Entity
@IdClass(RdaId.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Rda {

    @Id
    public String idDivisione;
    @Id
    public Integer esercizio;
    @Id
    public String idRda;
    
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="id_divisione", referencedColumnName = "id_divisione"),
        @JoinColumn(name="esercizio", referencedColumnName = "esercizio"),
        @JoinColumn(name="id_rda", referencedColumnName = "id_rda")
    })
    @OrderBy("nrRiga")
    public List<RdaRiga> righe = new ArrayList<>();     

    //Additional fields
}
```

where

```
public class RdaId implements Serializable {
    String idDivisione;
    Integer esercizio;
    String idRda;
}
```

The entity for the rows is

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@IdClass(RdaRigaId.class)
@Table(name = "ao_rda_acq_righe")
public class RdaRiga {

    @Id
    public String idDivisione;
    @Id
    public Integer esercizio;
    @Id
    public String idRda;
    @Id
    public Long nrRiga; 
    
    //More fields
}
```

where

```
public class RdaRigaId implements Serializable {
    String idDivisione;
    Integer esercizio;
    String idRda;
    Long nrRiga;
}
```

This code compiles but JPA at start-up complains with this message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [ao_rda_acq_righe] contains physical column name [id_divisione] referred to by multiple logical column names: [id_divisione], [idDivisione]
```

Is this approch the best one to map my unhappy DB structure? If so what did I miss?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on this, but shouldn't the main entity have an id field of type RdaId rather than three id fields using the individual columns? And the same for the child type. Plus the fields in the key classes need column annotations to set names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `@Id` without the `@Column` annotation, the name of the column is assumed to be the name of the annotated property.
Given that your DB column seems to be `*id_divisione*` you need to use also the annotation `@Column(name = "id_divisione")`.

This also applies to the other properties annotated with `@Id`.

Comment: Now sping run and was able to read the header object but the resulting query when JPA reads the rows table is select *
from ao_rda_acq_righe righe0_
where righe0_.id_divisione=<parent-esercizio> and righe0_.esercizio=<parent-id_divisione> and righe0_.id_rda=<id_rda> order by righe0_.nr_riga. Where id_divisione and esercizio are in reverse order

Comment: Solved. I've added referencedColumnName and now works. I've updated my orginal post hopping this makes it easier for reader. @JoinColumn(name="id_divisione", referencedColumnName = "id_divisione")